# is there a code to open all comments on a facebook page?

Tags: facebook, view, comments

there's an 'invite all your friends' javascript

```
javascript:elms=document.getElementById('friends').getElementsByTagName('li');for(var fid in elms){if(typeof elms[fid] === 'object'){fs.click(elms[fid]);}}
```

i wondered can you do the same thing to show all comments on a facebook post? rather than clicking 'View more comments' 25 times?

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10151622418903463&set=a.90133653462.85142.8245623462&type=1